# Julia Clear variables/workspace with the most recent update of Atom

Tags: variables, julia

I knew there's several post of how to clear workspace and variables for the previous versions of julia.

However, I'm using Julia v"1.0.3" with the most recent update of Atom.
I also have the most recent version of Julia "1.1.0"

However, I have tried

```
x=49

workspace()
clear!(:x)
# and even
clearconsole() # working but just clear the concle
Control + l # working but just clear the concle
```

Non of them clear the variables for me.
Also, workspace() and clear!(:x) return the error message

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: julia not defined
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Could you help me to figure out how to clear the variable in Julia? (Clear individual x and/or the entire workspace)Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Atom doesn't seem to find Julia. You may need to add the path to Julia if it is not accessible via the command `julia`. To do so, go to Packages > Julia > Settings and in the first box for "Julia Path" insert the path to your Julia installation (example: `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.0\bin\julia.exe`)

Comment: The julia was working, and I also tried the julia core directly.

Answer (score 0):

workspace() has been removed in Julia 1.0 as it was buggy and not flexible.

The preferred approach is now to use the [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) package.

Comment: Thank you. But do you know which specific code to do it? I read through the documentation and didn't find it.